# How to install these libraries and make them found by configure?

Tags: python, c, linux, gcc, waf

I am trying to configure the PLC (Planck Likelihood) using waf. I keep getting the following error after running `./waf configure CC=gcc --cfitsio_lib=/opt/local/lib --cfitsio_include=/opt/local/include --lapack_mkl=${MKLROOT} --install_all_deps --pmc_prefix=/opt/local/`:

```
Testing pyembed configuration                                              : Could not build a python embedded interpreter 
No suitable python distribution found 
Cause : 'The configuration failed
(complete log in /Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/config.log)' 
Compilation will continue without it (but I strongly advise that you install it) 
Checking for library dl                                                    : yes 
checking for RTLD_DEFAULT in dl                                            : yes 
compile with debug option                                                  : OFF 
Checking for program 'pmc-config'                                          : not found 
Checking for library pmc                                                   : not found
```

Below is the relevant part of the `config.log` for the attempt. It looks like the error above is caused by the waf not being able to find two libraries: `intl` and `plc`. My questions are 1) how can I check for sure if the libraries are installed? 2) How do I install them exactly and how do I make waf able to find them? When I run `locate plc` and `locate intl` I don't see them in any of the obvious places (`/usr/local` or `/opt/local`). Also, is `-lintl` the same as `libintl`?

Thank you for any guidance on these issues! I have been struggling with these for a while.

```
[1/2] Compiling [32mbuild/.conf_check_6b4b67dc94b05606ea0f210c0718a6fb/test.c[0m

['gcc', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-fno-common', '-dynamic', '-Os', '-isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk', '-DNDEBUG', '-g', '-fwrapv', '-O3', '-I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7', '-DPYTHONDIR="/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python2.7/site-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python2.7/site-packages"', '../test.c', '-c', '-o/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/.conf_check_6b4b67dc94b05606ea0f210c0718a6fb/testbuild/test.c.1.o']
[2/2] Linking [33mbuild/.conf_check_6b4b67dc94b05606ea0f210c0718a6fb/testbuild/testprog[0m

['gcc', '-arch', 'x86_64', 'test.c.1.o', '-o/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/.conf_check_6b4b67dc94b05606ea0f210c0718a6fb/testbuild/testprog', '-L/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib', '-L/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config', '-lm', '-ldl', '-lutil', '-lpthread', '-lpython2.7', '-lintl', '-ldl', '-lpython2.7', '-lintl', '-ldl']
err: ld: library not found for -lintl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

from /Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01: Test does not build: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/.waf-2.0.17-c5414c9b1eca70e1add79159e16494fe/waflib/Configure.py", line 325, in run_build
    bld.compile()
  File "/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/.waf-2.0.17-c5414c9b1eca70e1add79159e16494fe/waflib/Build.py", line 176, in compile
    raise Errors.BuildError(self.producer.error)
BuildError: Build failed
 -> task in 'testprog' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)

Could not build a python embedded interpreter
from /Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01: The configuration failed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Checking for library dl
==>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void)argc; (void)argv;
    return 0;
}

<==
[1/2] Compiling [32mbuild/.conf_check_428ef212807c68d65d8589da073dadd1/test.c[0m

['gcc', '-DPYTHONDIR="/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python2.7/site-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python2.7/site-packages"', '../test.c', '-c', '-o/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/.conf_check_428ef212807c68d65d8589da073dadd1/testbuild/test.c.1.o']
[2/2] Linking [33mbuild/.conf_check_428ef212807c68d65d8589da073dadd1/testbuild/testprog[0m

['gcc', '-arch', 'x86_64', 'test.c.1.o', '-o/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/.conf_check_428ef212807c68d65d8589da073dadd1/testbuild/testprog', '-ldl']
yes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
checking for RTLD_DEFAULT in dl
==>
#include <dlfcn.h> 
int main() {void* tt = RTLD_DEFAULT;}
<==
[1/2] Compiling [32mbuild/.conf_check_715de422e26f8311e37510f895dc2cf9/test.c[0m

['gcc', '-DPYTHONDIR="/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python2.7/site-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python2.7/site-packages"', '-DHAS_RTLD_DEFAULT', '../test.c', '-c', '-o/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/.conf_check_715de422e26f8311e37510f895dc2cf9/testbuild/test.c.1.o']
[2/2] Linking [33mbuild/.conf_check_715de422e26f8311e37510f895dc2cf9/testbuild/testprog[0m

['gcc', '-arch', 'x86_64', 'test.c.1.o', '-o/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/.conf_check_715de422e26f8311e37510f895dc2cf9/testbuild/testprog', '-ldl']
yes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
compile with debug option
OFF
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Checking for program 'pmc-config'
not found
find program=['pmc-config'] paths=['/opt/local//bin'] var='PMC_CONFIG' -> None
from /Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01: Could not find the program ['pmc-config']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Checking for library pmc
==>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void)argc; (void)argv;
    return 0;
}

<==
[1/2] Compiling [32mbuild/.conf_check_f81a3c4e05449ea9374b388f617e5f06/test.c[0m

['gcc', '-I/opt/local/include', '-I/opt/local/include/pmclib', '-I/opt/local/include/pmctools', '-DPYTHONDIR="/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python2.7/site-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python2.7/site-packages"', '-DHAS_PMC', '../test.c', '-c', '-o/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/.conf_check_f81a3c4e05449ea9374b388f617e5f06/testbuild/test.c.1.o']
[2/2] Linking [33mbuild/.conf_check_f81a3c4e05449ea9374b388f617e5f06/testbuild/testprog[0m

['gcc', '-arch', 'x86_64', 'test.c.1.o', '-o/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/.conf_check_f81a3c4e05449ea9374b388f617e5f06/testbuild/testprog', '-Wl,-rpath,/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib', '-Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-lpmc']
err: ld: library not found for -lpmc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

from /Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01: Test does not build: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/.waf-2.0.17-c5414c9b1eca70e1add79159e16494fe/waflib/Configure.py", line 325, in run_build
    bld.compile()
  File "/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/.waf-2.0.17-c5414c9b1eca70e1add79159e16494fe/waflib/Build.py", line 176, in compile
    raise Errors.BuildError(self.producer.error)
BuildError: Build failed
 -> task in 'testprog' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)

not found
from /Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01: The configuration failed
```

Comment: Can you show your wscript? I would guess your search paths are'nt correctly set.